# I am trying to perform a simple linear regression on a csv data set, but R won't read the dataset

Tags: read.csv

I am running the code below to use a CSV file so that I can perform a linear regression. A few fixes I found here and on other sites included the "setwd" command and closing the CSV file before running the command. I am still generating the error.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Tommy/Desktop/") 
dataset = file.choose("Project_subset.csv")
dataset = read.csv("dataset")`

> dataset = read.csv("dataset")
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'dataset': No such file or directory
```

I appreciate the help on a simple problem.

I entered several different codes to read the csv file and none have been successful. I keep getting the error above that the file does not exist. I also used the file.exist() code and it returned FALSE. I am very confused as this seems to be a simple command to use.

Comment: Can you try `dataset = read.csv("dataset.csv")` or `dataset = read.csv("C:\\Users\\Tommy\\Desktop\\dataset.csv")`? Please tell me if it helped.

Comment: Bingo! The read.csv("C:\\Users\\Tommy\\Desktop\\dataset.csv") worked. I appreciate the assist!

Comment: Cool. Can you upvote the previous comment, please?